# Show locations where there is only one item left

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, aggregate, having

I want to display all the locations that have only one item left. Tried using SUM function but it still gives me multiple rows with the same location, 3 article nr that have sum of 1

`SELECT location, artnr, sum(qty)
FROM location_stock
GROUP BY location, artnr
HAVING sum(qty) = 1`

RESULT:

`Location  Art Nr  Sum(Qty)
12345     5345    1
12345     5874    1
12345     4756    1`

What I want is locations that have one article nr and one qty:

`Location  Art Nr  Sum(Qty)
12345     5345    1`

Comment: why you need only 5345 for column Art NR

Comment: it's just the example. In my example we have location 12345 where there are 3 articles. What I want is only the location that has one article.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `row_number()` window function

```
   select * from ( SELECT location, artnr, sum(qty) as s,
    row_number() over(partition by location order by artnr asc) rn
    FROM location_stock
    GROUP BY location, artnr
    HAVING sum(qty) = 1
    ) a where a.rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming quantity is never negative or zero, then this should work:

```
SELECT location, max(artnr) as artnr, sum(qty)
FROM location_stock
GROUP BY location
HAVING SUM(qty) = 1;
```

For the more general solution:

```
SELECT location, max(artnr) as artnr, sum(qty)
FROM location_stock
GROUP BY location
HAVING MIN(artnr) = MAX(artnr) AND
       SUM(qty) = 1;
```

If you don't actually care about the quantity but only one `artnr`, then remove the condition on `SUM(qty)`.